# How to send a message using TCP/IP to a multicast address in java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, multicastsocket

Is it same as sending to any other IP address or is it different?

Answer (score 2):

Multicast messages can not be sent via TCP protocol (as it requires message receival confirmation). They are dispatched using UDP. For that purpose Java has a [MulticastSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) class.

There is quite short and self-explanatory tutorial here: [Broadcasting to Multiple Recipients](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html)